# pulling PHP array from python output

Tags: php, python

I currently have a python script that runs a query on a MSSQL server that returns the rows as a tuple and prints them to standard output, where the webpage runs PHP to fget the output and print it to the page. Is there some way to instead use the output of the script to create an array in PHP so i can format it as a table? I'm not able to directly query the MSSQL db from PHP because there is incompatibility with 64-bit WAMP. Using PHP 5.3, python 3.3

Comment: You should try encoding it. Encode the python data with `json.dumps` and then load it in php with `json_decode`. Not sure how you're transferring the data (I assume a file by the fget) but that would be my suggestion for the simplest way. The harder way would be to format the output from the python script and then parse it in php to format it in an array. There's a bunch of different ways this could be handled (csv).

Comment: why are you doing this? why not just do the query in php? or even better do it all in python ...?